# Laravel 5 : emanuelzh/loptimizer installation

Tags: php, laravel

I installed emanuelzh/loptimizer for Laravel 5 (on Ubuntu). It is a fork from https://github.com/approached/laravel-image-optimizer
It is for image optimization.

I successfully installed it with composer:

> ## composer.phar require emanuelzh/loptimizer
>
> Using version ^1.0 for emanuelzh/loptimizer ./composer.json has been
>   updated php artisan clear-compiled Loading composer repositories with
>   package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   - Installing emanuelzh/loptimizer (1.0.0) Downloading: 100%          Writing lock file Generating autoload files php artisan optimize
>   Generating optimized class loader

But the problem is with config/app.php file. I added the following line but it doesn't work when I try to publish.

config/app.php:

> Emanuelzh\Loptimizer\ServiceProvider::class,

Publish command:

> ## php artisan vendor:publish

Result of publish command:

> Nothing to publish for tag [].

Do you know what is the correct line to add in config/app.php ?

Thanks for your help.

Remy

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Finally I found the answer :)

The line to add in config/app.php is:

> Approached\LaravelImageOptimizer\ServiceProvider::class,

and for the facade:

> 'ImageOptimizer'      => Approached\LaravelImageOptimizer\ImageOptimizer::class,

Hope it helps!

Comment: You might be better raising a pull request or issue on the github package, so that this helps the other users.